# Xcode 8 - symbolicatecrash failed

Tags: xcode8, symbolicatecrash

Under Xcode 8 `symbolicatecrash` to analyse crash report failed with:

```
sh: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun: No such file or directory
## Warning: can't find tool named 'otool' in iOS SDK, falling back to searching the Mac OS X SDK
sh: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun: No such file or directory
Error: can't find tool named 'otool' in the macosx SDK or any fallback SDKs at /usr/local/bin/symbolicatecrash line 115.
```

how to solve it?

Comment: please edit your question and provide your detailed question, what do you want and when do you get this error.

Comment: We ran into same problem after updating from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find /Applications/Xcode.app/ -name symbolicatecrash`

then, you will get

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for the new location of `symbolicatecrash` in XCode 8?

Now it is located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources`

Comment: That's it! Thx a lot!